# How to make the searchfiles method case-insensitive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I am writing to you because i have some issues with my function that search files in a folder by checking if the key word is in, the problem is that the research is case-sensitive.
Here is the code i am trying to make case insensitive:

```
Folder.searchFiles("fullText contains  \'\"" + searchField + "\"\'" )
```

I have tried to put REGEX in but it does not recognize REGEX, i am a bit new to google app script  and it would be very kind if someone could help me with this problem, i have tried to find an answer in forums but it seems that there is no similar cases, thank you
Best regards

Comment: Hi ! This method is already by default case-insensitive, I have tested the following: ```var searchField = "test";
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(
    "fullText contains  \'\"" + searchField + "\"\'" );
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  Logger.log(file.getName());
}``` and I am getting the title of those files that contain the word test, Test and even TEST.

Comment: Thank Very much for your help.

Comment: Did it work? If it did I will formalise the comment in an answer.

Comment: Yes it worked, in fact the problem came from the fact that my var searchField was not really a string and i saw it thanks to your script. So  thank you again,Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

The method `searchFiles` is already case-insensitive BUT **you must make sure that your searchField in this case is of the type** `String`.

#### Working example

```js
function searchForFiles(){
  var searchField = "test";
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles( "fullText contains \'\"" + searchField + "\"\'" );
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next(); Logger.log(file.getName());
  }
}
```

For more information regarding this method, [check here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams).

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)